# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to MyUser

Tags: spring-security

This is a spring security question.

I want to be able to retrieve my custom User object object using

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

because I need additional details like user id and stuff for further business logic in my classes.

For this, I have a custom class derived from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl where I've overriden loadUsersByUsername() to populate additional user fields and return an object of MyUser with the extra fields like user id etc.

Code -

```
public class MyJdbcDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl {

@Override
protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(getUsersByUsernameQuery(), new String[] {username}, new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
        public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Long id = rs.getLong(1);
            String username = rs.getString(2);
            String password = rs.getString(3);
            boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(4);
            MyUser user = new MyUser(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);
            user.setId(id);
            return user;
        }

    });
}
}
```

My application context -

```
<beans:bean id="myJdbcDaoImpl" class="package.MyJdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="securityDB"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select username,role_id from app_user,user_role where app_user.id = user_role.user_id and username=?"/>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select id,username,password,account_enabled from app_user where username = ?"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="myJdbcDaoImpl">
       <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
</authentication-provider>
```

The issue is, when I do a

```
MyUser user = (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I get an exception 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to package.MyUser

What should I do to access my user object with additional fields from SecurityContextHolder?

Thanks

Comment: In debug, what's runtime class of object returned from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`?

Comment: The spring default user class - org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

Comment: Can you show us `package.MyJdbcDaoImpl` code by editing your question?

Comment: Think I figured out what the issue is..I am not overriding loadUserByUsername(String username) and JdbcDaoImpl's implementation returns a 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User' object.

Comment: @hese Can you please post full code and how did that worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've overriden wrong method, additionally override `createUserDetails` which creates final User object from these fetched via `loadUsersByUsername`:

```
@Override
protected UserDetails createUserDetails(final String username,
    final UserDetails userFromUserQuery,
    final List<GrantedAuthority> combinedAuthorities) {
  String returnUsername = userFromUserQuery.getUsername();

  if (!isUsernameBasedPrimaryKey()) {
    returnUsername = username;
  }

  final MyUser userToReturn = new MyUser(returnUsername,
      userFromUserQuery.getPassword(), userFromUserQuery.isEnabled(), true,
      true, true, combinedAuthorities);
  userToReturn.setId(((MyUser) userFromUserQuery).getId());
  return userToReturn;
}
```

`userToReturn.setId(((MyUser) userFromUserQuery).getId());` will work if you used your code, or you can remove `loadUsersByUsername` and fetch id right inside `createUserDetails` which doc's says:

> Can be overridden to customize the creation of the final
>   UserDetailsObject which is returned by the loadUserByUsername
>   method.

Comment: Great, I'll change my implementation to override createUserDetails().  Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: remember that userFromUserQuery will be `MyUser` instance only if you overriden loadUsersByUsername too and as alternative you can leave loadUsersByUsername and fetch id directly inside createUserDetails ;)

Comment: @Xaerxess I am facing the same problem and I tried your code but no luck. So finally I have created a question can you please see and tell me where I am going wrong. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548391/org-springframework-security-core-userdetails-user-cannot-be-cast-to-myuserdetai)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question -

The issue was not overriding loadUserByUsername(String username) from JdbcDaoImpl.

Therefore JdbcDaoImpl's implementation of loadUserByUsername(String username) was being called, which though internally was first calling loadUsersByUsername(String username), was subsequently adding granted authorities to the MyUser object returned above and returning it as a org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User object.