# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to MyUserDetails

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting class cast exception when I implement User class of spring security. I want to add few additional details in MyUserDetails (id) but I am not able to get the result.

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078404/org-springframework-security-core-userdetails-user-cannot-be-cast-to-myuser) but then two I am getting error, don't know where I am missing.

Below is my code :

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.headers().cacheControl().and().xssProtection().and()
                .frameOptions().and();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sadmin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403").and().csrf();

        // session management URL for reference
        // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/spring-security-javaconfig/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/NamespaceSessionManagementTests.groovy
    }
```

**MyUserDetails.java:**

```
public class MyUserDetails extends User {
    private int id;

    public MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

    }
    // getter setter ....
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java:**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl{
    @Override
    protected List<UserDetails> loadUsersByUsername(String username) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(super.getUsersByUsernameQuery(), new String[] { username },
                new RowMapper<UserDetails>() {
                    public UserDetails mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        String username = rs.getString("username");
                        String password = rs.getString("password");
                        boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean("enabled");
                        boolean accountNonExpired = rs.getBoolean("accountNonExpired");
                        boolean credentialsNonExpired = rs.getBoolean("credentialsNonExpired");
                        boolean accountNonLocked = rs.getBoolean("accountNonLocked");
                        int id = rs.getInt("id");

                        MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
                                accountNonLocked, AuthorityUtils.NO_AUTHORITIES);

                        myUserDetails.setId(id);
                        return myUserDetails;
                    }

                });
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails createUserDetails(String username, UserDetails userFromUserQuery,
            List<GrantedAuthority> combinedAuthorities) {
        String returnUsername = userFromUserQuery.getUsername();

        if (!isUsernameBasedPrimaryKey()) {
            returnUsername = username;
        }

        final MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails(returnUsername, userFromUserQuery.getPassword(), userFromUserQuery.isEnabled(),
                userFromUserQuery.isAccountNonExpired(), userFromUserQuery.isCredentialsNonExpired(),
                userFromUserQuery.isAccountNonLocked(), combinedAuthorities);

        myUserDetails.setId(((MyUserDetails) userFromUserQuery).getId());
        return myUserDetails;
    }
}
```

**Code to get MyUserDetails:**

```
MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/housing] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.esociety.dto.MyUserDetails] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.esociety.dto.MyUserDetails
    at com.esociety.controller.LoginController.dashboard(LoginController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of Spring do you use? What stacktrace do you get? What's your XML / Java configuration for Spring Security?

Comment: @Xaerxess I have added spring version and stacktrace and I am using Java config. `<org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have similar "requirements" as you and for my it is working fine. My setup is as follows

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder);
    }

}
```

My guess is that your problem is with `auth.jdbcAuthentication()` as it will provide implementation of `UserDetailsService` that returns core security `User` and does not use your implementation at all. See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html#jdbcAuthentication()):

> Add JDBC authentication to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder and return
>   a JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer to allow customization of the JDBC
>   authentication. This method also ensure that a UserDetailsService is
>   available for the getDefaultUserDetailsService() method. Note that
>   additional UserDetailsService's may override this UserDetailsService
>   as the default.

Comment: Can you please help me with code for `Add JDBC authentication to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder and return a JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer to allow customization of the JDBC authentication` and also I need to create AuthenticationConfiguration class?

Comment: that's from javadoc (it is quoted) and it should just explain why your solution might not work. my suggestion is to use `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)` instead of your `auth.jdbcAuthentication()`

Comment: Thank You very much your hint worked for me and I am posting full code if in case some one facing the same issue it would be easy for him.

Answer (score 5):

I have taken mkyong tutorial to add additional data in MyUserDetails (In my case email id). Please refer this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/) for full code, I am putting only those code were I did changes for getting email id.

Thank You all for your time and efforts.
User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "test")
public class User {

private String username;
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
private boolean accountNonExpired;
private boolean accountNonLocked;
private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
private String emailId;

private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled,boolean accountNonExpired,boolean accountNonLocked,boolean credentialsNonExpired, String emailId) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled,boolean accountNonExpired,boolean accountNonLocked,boolean credentialsNonExpired, Set<UserRole> userRole,String emailId) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    this.emailId = emailId;
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}


@Column(name = "accountNonExpired", nullable = false)
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return accountNonExpired;
}

public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
    this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
}

@Column(name = "accountNonLocked", nullable = false)
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return accountNonLocked;
}

public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
    this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
}

@Column(name = "credentialsNonExpired", nullable = false)
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return credentialsNonExpired;
}

public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
    this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
}

@Column(name = "emailId", nullable = false)
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return this.userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

}
```

MyUserDetails Class

```
public class MyUserDetails extends User {

private final String emailId;

public MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
        boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
        boolean accountNonLocked,String emailId,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

}
```

MyUserDetailsService Class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.mkyong.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.mkyong.users.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
     MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails (user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(), user.isAccountNonLocked(), user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), user.getEmailId(),authorities);
     return myUserDetails;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

}
```

Security Config class there is no change in this. This is exactly same as tutorial link but this was hint given by @sodik to change JDBCAuthentication

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

}
```

AppConfig adding password in this because password was not set in tutorial link

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mkyong.*" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

      BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
      ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/test");
      ds.setUsername("root");
      ds.setPassword("password");
      return ds;
    }
}
```