# Accessing UserDetails object from controller in Spring using Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to access some user details from session. I am using spring security and custom authentication by overriding **loadUserByUsername(String username)** method.

I am returning a user and would like to access it from within **my controller.** I tried the principal object but i can not reach to the companyId field of my **ESecurityUser** object.

Any help would be appreciated..

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    ESecurityUser user = new ESecurityUser();
    user.setUsername("hello");
    user.setPassword("world");
    user.setCompanyId(199);

    Set<EAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<EAuthority>();
    EAuthority authority = new EAuthority();
    authority.setAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
    authorities.add(authority);

    user.setAuthorities(authorities);;

    return user;
}
```

Sample Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping("")
    public String toPeriodicAdReport(@ModelAttribute("advertFormHelper") AdvertFormHelper advertFormHelper,
            Model model,Principal principal) {

        //What to write here so that i can access to authenticated user`s companyId field..

        return "Test";
    }
```

Comment: ESecurityUser user = (ESecurityUser) principal;

Comment: @brub Hello, I tried that but i got an exception.. `org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to tr.com.simroll.ada.rvm.report.entity.ESecurityUser`

Comment: this looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078404/org-springframework-security-core-userdetails-user-cannot-be-cast-to-myuser

Comment: The question should be edited with the exception. It really helps to understand what has happened under the hood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the annotation `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to directly access `ESecurityUser`.

```
@RequestMapping("")
public String toPeriodicAdReport(@ModelAttribute("advertFormHelper") AdvertFormHelper advertFormHelper,
        Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal ESecurityUser principal) {
    principal.getCompanyId();
    return "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not far...

The `Principal` that the SpringMVC machinery passed to a controller method is the `Authentication` token that identifies the user. You must use its `getDetails()` method to extract the `ESecurityUser` that you returned from your `loadUserByUsername`

Your code could become:

```
@RequestMapping("")
    public String toPeriodicAdReport(@ModelAttribute("advertFormHelper") AdvertFormHelper advertFormHelper,
            Model model,Principal principal) {

        ESecurityUser user = (ESecurityUser) ((Authentication) principal).getDetails();

        // stuff...
        return "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ESecurityUser e = (ESecurityUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

This is working for me..